# Solve system of ordinary differential equations that doesn't have an initial condition (t=0), but has an inifinity condition (t=infinity)?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have a question for solving `t -> Infinity` on *Mathematica*. First, I have a system of ODEs:

```
feqn1 = {x'[t] == -k1*x[t]*y[t]/h[t] + k2*z[t],
   y'[t] == 3*(-k1*x[t]*y[t]/h[t] + k2*z[t]),
   z'[t] == k1*x[t]*y[t]/h[t] - k2*z[t],
   h'[t] == -3*(-k1*x[t]*y[t]/h[t] + k2*z[t]),
   x[0] == .001, z[0] == 0, y[0] == 0.2, h[0] == .001};
```

Then I solved the equations by `NDSolve`.

```
NDSolve[feqn1, {x, y, z, h}, {t, 0, 1000}];
```

and for the second part of the problem, I have another set of ODE.

```
seqn1 = {x2'[t] == -k1*x2[t]*y[t]/h2[t] + k2*z[t],
         h2'[t] == -3*(-k1*x2[t]*y[t]/h2[t] + k2*z[t])}
```

The initial conditions are `h2[0] == 1` at `t = Infinity`, `x2 = 0.001`.

Thanks.

Comment: You can approximate the boundary condition at infinity with a suitably large number, e.g. `h2[1/$MachineEpsilon] == 1`. Also, see [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/Sep/msg00252.html), among a number of other old MathGroup posts on handling such boundary conditions.

Comment: An alternative is to change variables in your ODE so that infinity becomes 1 say (?)

Comment: Thanks J.M & Chris... I tried to look up the document, they used DShoot, but I couldn't find a command on Mathematica for "DShoot". And I also tried set x2[t=1000]= 0.001, but Mathematica only gave me error msg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments have made two suggestions - one that we change variables so that $[0,\infty)$ corresponds to a bounded region like $[0,1)$ and the other that we simply solve over a large interval of the form $[0,M]$.  Since you've already got InterpolatingFunctions defined over $[0,1000]$ in your system, I suppose that the second suggestion probably makes the most sense.  Also, as appealing as a change of variables sounds, in my experience this likely generates a singularlity at the right endpoint making anyway.

Here's your initial system; I grabbed values of $k_1$ and $k_2$ from another post.

```
Clear[x,y,z,h]
k1 = 0.000392;
k2 = 0.00759355499;
feqn1 = {x'[t] == -k1*x[t]*y[t]/h[t] + k2*z[t],
   y'[t] == 3*(-k1*x[t]*y[t]/h[t] + k2*z[t]),
   z'[t] == k1*x[t]*y[t]/h[t] - k2*z[t],
   h'[t] == -3*(-k1*x[t]*y[t]/h[t] + k2*z[t]),
   x[0] == .001, z[0] == 0, y[0] == 0.2, h[0] == .001};
{x,y,z,h} = {x,y,z,h} /. First[
  NDSolve[feqn1,{x,y,z,h},{t,0,1000}]
];
```

We'll use a shooting method to solve the boundary value problem.  That is, we'll write a function `shot` that solves an initial value problem in terms of a parameter `a`, with initial conditions at the left endpoint.  The idea is to choose the parameter `a` so that the right hand boundary condition is satisfied.  Here's `shot`:

```
Clear[shot];
shot[a_?NumericQ] := Module[{},
  solution = First[NDSolve[
     {x2'[t] == -k1*x2[t]*y[t]/h2[t] + k2*z[t],
      h2'[t] == -3*(-k1*x2[t]*y[t]/h2[t] + k2*z[t]),
      h2[0] == 1, x2[0] == a},
     {h2, x2}, {t, 0, 1000}]];
  {h2Try, x2Try} = {h2, x2} /. solution;
  x2Try[1000]]
Plot[shot[a], {a, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

The plot indicates that `shot` is one-to-one and that there's probably a unique solution to your problem.  We can find it with `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[shot[a] == 0.001, {a, 0}]

(* Out: {a -> -0.00479028} *)
```

Note that the solutions for $x_2$ and $h_2$ are already stored in the variables `x2Try` and `h2Try`.  We can plot them over various intervals as below.  I'm actually plotting $x_2(t)$ and $h_2(t)-1$ here since, otherwise, they look like two flat lines.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{x2Try[t], h2Try[t] - 1}, {t, 0, max}],
 {{max, 1}, 0.1, 1000}]
```

[image]

Comment: If need be, one could save on memory in the definition of `shot[]` by having the start and endpoints in the integration interval coincide: `x2[1000] /. First @ NDSolve[(* equations *), {h2, x2}, {t, 1000, 1000}]`.

Comment: @ Mark McClure: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still trying to figure out "a" because according to your answer, it seems like at t=0, x2=a, which equals to some values. But in my case, at t=0, x2=0 and t=inifinity, x2=0.001 is the boundary conditions. Maybe I misunderstood something here...

Comment: @DumbleKo At no point in your question do I see a specification for `x2[0]`, which is a good thing! You've got a first order system in the two unknown functions `h2` and `x2` - correct?  You've already specified that `h2[0]==1`. If you additionally specify that `x2[0]==0`, then your solution is uniquely determined so you can't expect to force the value of `x2` at infinity. If you want some particular value for `x2` at infinity, then you might be able to get it, if you allow flexibility at zero. That's the approach taken here.

Comment: @ Mark McClure: I see. Sorry I was confused by the my question and trying to solve this problems from different approach. But thanks for answering all my questions. They've been very helpful.