# Trying to use NDSolve to solve Blasius equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

```
s = NDSolve[{f'''[eta] + 0.5*f[eta]*f''[eta] == 0.0, f[0] == 0.0, 
f'[0] == 0.0, f'[Infinity] = 1.0}, f, {eta, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate[f[eta] /. s], {eta, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I followed exactly the instructions from the site.
I get the following error (among others)

```
NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of 1.` in the first argument
```

Comment: You need `f'[Infinity] == 1.0` but still error will occur with this `Infinity` I guess!

Comment: It does not matter. I changed infinity to 10 and the same error comes up

Comment: At the moment in the above code you have a single `=` for your boundary condition at infinity. Changing it to a double equal (`==`) will help (as long as you quit the kernel). However, you need to define the boundary conditions within the region of integration, ie. between `eta=0` and `1`. Otherwise the algorithm doesn't know what value of `f'[eta]` to start iterating with.

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14259)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work if you replace `Infinity` with a smaller number :

```
s = NDSolve[{Derivative[3][f][x] + 1/2 f[x] Derivative[2][f][x] == 0, 
      f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f'[#] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ Range[1, 50, 5];

Plot[Evaluate[f[eta] /. s], {eta, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotLegends -> (ToString[#] & /@ Range[1, 50, 5])]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

As late as this answer may be:

```
sol = NDSolve[{f'''[η] + 0.5 f[η] f''[η] == 0, 
   f[0] == f'[0] == 0, f'[10] == 1}, f, η]
Plot[f[η] /. First[sol], {η, 0, 10}]
Plot[f'[η] /. First[sol], {η, 0, 10}]
Plot[f''[η] /. First[sol], {η, 0, 10}]
```

**Plot of f vs eta**

[image: Plot of f vs eta]

**Plot of f' vs eta (velocity profile)**

[image: Plot of f' vs eta (velocity profile)]

**Plot of f'' vs eta (shear stress distribution)**

[image: Plot of f'' vs eta (shear stress distribution)]