# Using NDSolve to obtain solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to solve the following ordinary differential equation but not getting result. P[image]lease help. Thanks

My code is

```
Eqn1 = 2 x f'''[x] + 2 f''[x] + f[x] f''[x] == 0

Eqn2 = 2 x T''[x] + 2 T'[x] + Pr f[x] T'[x] == 0

BC1 = f[c] == cL/2;

BC2 = f'[c] == L/2;

BC3 = f'[inf1] == (1 - L)/2;

BC4 = T'[c] == 1;

BC5 = T[inf1] == 0;

params = {Pr -> 3.97, c -> 0.1, L -> 3};

inf1 = 5;

sol = NDSolve[{Eqn1, BC1, BC2, BC3} /. params, {f}, {x, 0.1, inf1}] & /@
    Range[6, 11, 5];

s3 = Plot[Evaluate[f'[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> (ToString[#] & /@ Range[1, 0, 10])]
```

Comment: Change `BC1 = f[c] == cL/2;` to `BC1 = f[c] == c*L/2;` and you should see your plot. You might also try removing the `PlotRange->All` to see your result scaled differently.

Comment: Check [this also](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24427/trying-to-use-ndsolve-to-solve-blasius-equation).  You have a very similar situation to the Blasius equation, perhaps with heat transfer added?